# Radix sort using bitwise operations

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles, radix-sort

I need to create a method that does a radix sort which retrieves individual bits from a value using the bitwise operators(>>,<<,&,|).

The file looks something like this:

```
0100
1
0011
110
0010
101
0001
11
0000
```

I currently have read in the file(size of which is unknown).  At first I read them in as integers, but realized I was truncating leading zeroes.  So I stored them into a String[].

```
public static void readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File file = new File(fileName);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))
    {
        fis.read(bytes);
    }

    String[] value = new String(bytes).split("\\s+");
    numbers = new String[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, numbers, 0, value.length);

} // end of import file
```

That is my current method to import that file which is working.  I have all my other methods working, except the radix sort which I am not sure where to begin with in regards to bitwise operations.

I have the concept of how the sort works, but implementing it seems to be a bit more challenging.

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a recursive sorting dividing the array in 3 new ones: the one with next digit = 0, the one with next digit = 1 and the one with no next digit. So your numbers would be sorted as follows:

```
Input
0100
1
0011
110
0010
101
0001
11
0000

Step 1
 Array "no next" (empty)
 Array "next = 0"
 0100
 0011
 0010
 0001
 0000
 Array "next = 1"
 1
 110
 101
 11

Step 2 (only showing the array "next = 1")
 Array "no next"
  1
 Array "next = 0"
  101
 Array "next = 1"
  110
  11
```

Just keep going until you get 0 or 1 sized arrays so you know they are sorted. Then you would go back returning sorted arrays like in [Quicksort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)